# Spring scheduled task with jms

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-jms

I'm just starting out with Spring (specifically I'm staring with Spring Boot) and want to create long running program that works on a scheduled task (i.e. @Scheduled), e.g. start processing between 7pm and 11pm. I'm ok with this bit.

The task will take a message from an ActiveMQ queue and process it, sleep a little, then get another and repeat.

Being new to JMS/ActiveMQ also, is it possible to use the Spring @JmsListener in conjunction with the scheduler to achieve this, and if so how?

If not, I take it my scheduled task should simply use point to point access to the queue to pull messages off. If so, does anyone have a simple example as I prefer to use Spring boot but can't find any good examples, they all seem to use listeners.

thanks.

Comment: Euh. Don't... Create a Spring Batch Job (still using Spring Boot) and just create a cron schedule to start your app around 7pm and have the job process the stuff from the queue. Also the fact of using Spring Boot has nothing to do with the fact of using `@JmsListener` or not. Looks like you are confusing things.

Comment: @M.Deinum I would say using JMS here is good.You can listen the queue and run jobs. Cron scheduler could just place events in the queue. It's more flexible you can schedule the spring batch or fire the even manually.

Comment: Kind of depends on what kind of complexity and tradeoff really wanted. Just using JMSTemplate and calling receive() could perhaps be the starting point?

Comment: @StanislavL Where do I state he shouldn't use JMS? Spring Batch is perfectly capable of reading from JMS. You can write a batch job, launch that at the scheduled time (which is what I responded to) and have a batch job with a `JmsItemReader` which wraps a `JmsTemplate` to read the messages from a destination.

Comment: @M.Deinum spring batch supposes some steps - reader, processor, writer. Could be an extra level of abstraction (not sure it's necessary)

Comment: Well he clearly want to read from the queue and process the messages. Ofcourse you can write your own infrastructure for it... But again you reacted on the JMS part and I nowhere said he should abandon that.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at Spring Batch, it seemed a bit heavy weight when I first looked. I wanted to use scheduler to keep everything in one place rather than relying on a cron job (I'm running on Windows too so would have to use Windows scheduler). 

As for processing/writing, I'm taking the message from the queue and using Jasper to create a PDF and store it.